# my regex work on online test but not in my c# app

Tags: c#, regex, xamarin

I have a regex pattern `(?<=base64,)(.*?)(?=")` to get part of text.
This pattern [works in an online tester web site](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Dbase64%2C%29%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%22%29&i=%09%09imga%09%22data%3Aimage%2FJpeg%3Bbase64%2C%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD%2F2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL%2F2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL%2FwAARCAF7ArcDASIAAhEBAxEB%2F8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAk%2Frc8Wo%2BIIZLPTFIZYGBWW474x1Vfc8%2BnqPbdD8D%2BGNAKS6Zo1rDMOkrAyOPozEkfnXR1pGHcxlV6IjhhitreOCGNY4o1CIijAUAYAA9MUVLRWhif%2FZ%22%09string%0D%0A), but in my C# app always returns false in `IsMatch()` and return empty in `Match()`.

```
string imga = _blogPosts[position].PostImage;
if (_blogPosts[position].PostImage !=null)
{
    Regex re2 = new Regex(@"(?<=base64,)(.*?)(?="")");
    bool m = re2.IsMatch(imga); // always retun false
}
```

Can anyone help me?
[reg pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoIsB.jpg)

Comment: Try to escape the two consecutive double quotes => `?=\"` and remove the @ before the string

Comment: There is no `"` at the end of your string. Use `@"(?<=base64,)\S+"` and if you plan to actually get the value, use `re2.Match`.

Comment: @sle1306 `new Regex("(?<=base64,)(.*?)(?=\")");` still return false

Comment: @arman That is because there is no `"`. And `@"\""` is not a valid verbatim string literal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , no end of my string have `"` , `"data:image/Jpeg;base64,9j/OPozEktreOC.....GNY4o1CIijAUAYAA9MUVLRWhif/Z"`

Comment: @arman you are wrong, the *string* you have **does not** contain a single `"` char. Run my code from the answer, and you will get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you copied into RegexStorm is just the debugger row data. There is no actual `"` in your string.

Note that there is no sense using the regex for this task, you might as well use

```
if (imga !=null && imga.Contains("base64,"))  { /* yes */ }
```

If you need to actually grab all non-whitespace characters after `base64,` substring, you might use

```
Regex re2 = new Regex(@"base64,(\S+)");
Match m = re2.Match(imga);
string result = "";
if (m.Success)
{
    result = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

See the [regex demo used above](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=base64%2C%28%5CS%2B%29&i=data%3Aimage%2FJpeg%3Bbase64%2C%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD%2F2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL%2F2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL%2FwAARCAF7ArcDASIAAhEBAxEB%2F8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2F8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAk%2Frc8Wo%2BIIZLPTFIZYGBWW474x1Vfc8%2BnqPbdD8D%2BGNAKS6Zo1rDMOkrAyOPozEkfnXR1pGHcxlV6IjhhitreOCGNY4o1CIijAUAYAA9MUVLRWhif%2FZ%0D%0A). `(\S+)` captures into Group 1 any one or more non-whitespace chars after a `base64,` substring.

But you can really get it using a `Substring`:

```
string result = "";
if (imga !=null && imga.Contains("base64,")) 
{
    result = imga.Substring(imga.IndexOf("base64,")+7);
}
```

Comment: You are right. Characters are "a string sign!". My bad brain